# Why do I get empty django querysets when using ThreadPoolExecutor with pytest-django?

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I have been trying to track down some bugs in some concurrent code and wanted to write a test that ran a function in parallel. I am using Django with postgres as my database and testing using pytest and pytest-django.

To run my function, I am using `ThreadPoolExecutor` and simply querying my database and returning a count of objects. Here is the test in the django shell working as expected:

```py
>>> from concurrent.futures import *
>>> def count_accounts():
...     return Account.objects.all().count()
...
>>> count_accounts()
2
>>> with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as e:
...     future = e.submit(count_accounts)
...
>>> for f in as_completed([future]):
...     print(f.result())
...
2
```

However, when I run this as a test under pytest, it appears like the function in the thread returns empty querysets:

```py
class TestCountAccounts(TestCase):
    def test_count_accounts(self):
        def count_accounts():
            return Account.objects.all().count()

        initial_result = count_accounts()  # 2
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as e:
            future = e.submit(count_accounts)

        for f in as_completed([future]):
            assert f.result() == initial_result  # 0 != 2
```

Is there anyway I can get the call inside the thread to return the correct value/access the db correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `TransactionTestCase` instead of `TestCase`. `TestCase` wraps the class with `atomic()` and each test with `atomic()`, so it's likely that the thread is executing outside of the transaction where your test data is being created.

For more information on the difference between the two: http://rahmonov.me/posts/testcase-vs-transactiontestcase-in-django/

Answer (score 3):

Following on @marquee's answer above, if you are using pytest and django and using `futures` in one of your tests, you'll need to modify your test function decorator. Instead of just

```
@pytest.mark.django_db`
def test_something():
    ...
```

Use:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)`
def test_something():
    ...
```

which achieves the same result.